# How to align buttons properly

Tags: php

I am using below code on my function.php file to display two buttons.

```
function action_after_question_content() {
    if (!is_single()) {
        echo "<a class='button-default' href='".get_the_permalink()."#respond'>See Answer</a>";
        echo "<a class='meta-answer' href='".get_the_permalink()."#comments'>Give Answer</a>";
    }
}
```

This is working fine but those buttons alignment is not coming properly as you can see on small screen. May I know how can we create different class/div so that they appear smaller and align properly.

Thanks,
Avinash
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first things first lets improve your code:

```
function action_after_question_content() {
    if (!is_single()) {
        echo "<a class='button-default' href='".esc_url( get_the_permalink() )."#comments'>See Answers</a>";
        echo "<a class='meta-answer' href='".esc_url( get_the_permalink() )."#respond'>Give Answer</a>";
    }
}
```

Note: We can improve further by getting the numbers of comments, and based on that build the buttons: Ex: If we have a plural numbers of comments we will use "See Answers", if we have one, we will use "See Answer", If we have none, we can display something like "Be the first who answers!"

This will look like:

```
function action_after_question_content() {
    if (!is_single()) {
        $num_comments = get_comments_number();
        if ( $num_comments ) :
            echo '<a class="button-default btn-puzzle-align" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#comments">' . _n( 'See Answer', 'See Answers', $num_comments, 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
            echo '<a class="meta-answer btn-puzzle-align" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#respond">' . __( 'Give Answer', 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
        else :
            echo '<a class="meta-answer btn-puzzle-align" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#respond">' . __( 'Be the first to answer!', 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
        endif;
    }
}
```

Where in CSS should look like:

```
.btn-puzzle-align {
   margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
```

This is just a guessing, the margin-bot could not work but could work depending on the others elements CSS. The code is also untested. Note that you need to change the textdomain to the theme textdomain, and the 2.5rem to what you might need.

Edit:

Also, after writing this, a more good way of doing this is maybe to wrap the buttons in another element:

```
function action_after_question_content() {
    if (!is_single()) {
        $num_comments = get_comments_number();
        echo '<div class="btn-puzzle-align">';
            if ( $num_comments ) :
                echo '<a class="ap-see" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#comments">' . _n( 'See Answer', 'See Answers', $num_comments, 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="ap-give" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#respond">' . __( 'Give Answer', 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
            else :
                echo '<a class="ap-see" href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '#respond">' . __( 'Be the first to answer!', 'textdomain' ) . '</a>';
            endif;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

And use the padding, which will usually work.

```
.btn-puzzle-align {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}
.btn-puzzle-align > .ap-see, .btn-puzzle-align > .ap-give{
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brada, there was no improvement on button appearance on smaller device.

Comment: Hi... I looked into your website and saw that you added float: left and float:right, that will cause the container to not calculate the height of the float contents.

Comment: you need to add .question-content-text{ overflow:hidden;} if you want to use floats

Comment: I updated my answer, don't forget to add a wrapper around those buttons, you don't have one.

Comment: Thanks Brada, i tried your new code also but still it is not looking good on small screen. you can see it here https://ibb.co/cNh1f0G  ow i am giving up this idea to keep two buttons over there. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: that's because you have different classes on links, one has "button-default" and one has meta-answer, one of them have something more than the other...  I saw your site using ap-see and ap-give... and i forgot to update the php code with that... now i updated

Comment: Hi Brada, i have done this, slightly different though, while using most of your code so tat you again. You can check on website. By the way i am now looking for the option to see full post on home page rather than excerpt.

Comment: It looks good, but not perfect... If you want to do it better... modify the css with these:

.question-content-text {
    padding: 10px 20px 50px 10px;
    background-image: url(../TBG1), url(../Design2.JPG), 
   url(../mainbg);
    background-position: 10px 99%, top left, bottom right;
    max-height: none !important;
}

What we do: first, we don't need a maxim height, the content will just fit perfectly inside the box wrapper, next, we will make the padding bottom 50px, to make sure that askpuzzle.com site will be displayed, and next, we put the askpuzzle.com image to be first.